# When Required field validator fires when it enabled and showing Error messages...?

Tags: asp.net, jquery-validate, validation, requiredfieldvalidator

I have 1 dropdown List and it contains 3 items like Email, Message and Phone. Based on selection of dropdown we are showing text boxes remaining all text boxes are in invisible.
We are using Requiredfield  validator (RFV1,RFV2) for these textboxes and based on selection enableing RFV's here we are facing the problem enabling RFV's by javascript function at the same it selfs showing all the Error messages.

So, how to prevent error messages showing on Enable of RFV's.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Required field validator for invisible textboxes also fires, or it fires ass soon as you make them visible?  Not quite sure what you're asking.

Comment: @R0MANARMY: First I'm Checking whickh textboxs are enabled for those controls only assigning RFV means enabling RFV.But when i enable RFV at the time itselef showing error messages.final suubmission of texboxes only I want to show error messages.

Comment: Can you show some code ? maybe you need to set **InitialValue** for your validators

Comment: show `aspx` please to more clarification, may be you are supposed to use validation group.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Validation Group. You can use ValidationGroup which would allow specific buttons to handle specific validation group marked controls only.

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227424.aspx) for more information